# Error:Internal error: (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException) in flutter

Tags: flutter

**I am using flutter app by IntelliJ IDEA version before two days was working will but now when i do build show error**

**this flutter doctor**

> [√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.9.1+hotfix.6, on Microsoft Windows
>   [Version 10.0.17134.1304], locale en-US)
>       • Flutter version 1.9.1+hotfix.6 at C:\src\flutter
>       • Framework revision 68587a0916 (6 months ago), 2019-09-13 19:46:58 -0700
>       • Engine revision b863200c37
>       • Dart version 2.5.0
>
> [√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK
>   version 28.0.3)
>       • Android SDK at C:\Users\Ahmed\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
>       • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
>       • Platform android-29, build-tools 28.0.3
>       • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
>       • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03)
>       • All Android licenses accepted.
>
> [√] Android Studio (version 3.5)
>       • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
>       • Flutter plugin version 42.1.1
>       • Dart plugin version 191.8593
>       • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03)
>
> [√] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2019.3)
>       • IntelliJ at C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3
>       • Flutter plugin version 42.1.4
>       • Dart plugin version 193.5731
>
> [!] VS Code (version 1.42.1)
>       • VS Code at C:\Users\Ahmed\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
>       X Flutter extension not installed; install from
>         https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter
>
> [√] Connected device (1 available)
>       • SM J727R4 • 93616a8f • android-arm64 • Android 7.0 (API 24)
>
> ! Doctor found issues in 1 category.

**error show this**

```
> Error:Internal error: (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException)
> javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema   at
> java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)
>   at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
>   at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
>   at
> com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:157)
>   at
> com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:76)
>   at
> com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:82)
>   at
> org.jetbrains.jps.android.AndroidJpsUtil.getAndroidTarget(AndroidJpsUtil.java:405)
>   at
> org.jetbrains.jps.android.AndroidJpsUtil.getAndroidPlatform(AndroidJpsUtil.java:481)
>   at
> org.jetbrains.jps.android.builder.AndroidPreDexBuildTarget.computeRootDescriptors(AndroidPreDexBuildTarget.java:111)
>   at
> org.jetbrains.jps.builders.impl.BuildRootIndexImpl.addRoots(BuildRootIndexImpl.java:72)
>   at
> org.jetbrains.jps.builders.impl.BuildRootIndexImpl.<init>(BuildRootIndexImpl.java:62)
>   at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.load(BuildRunner.java:83)
>   at
> org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:274)
>   at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:130)
>   at
> org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler.lambda$channelRead0$0(BuildMain.java:232)
>   at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
>   at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
>   at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```